# I try connect my java program to MySQL database , and i received this exception

Tags: java, mysql, swing, exception, jdbc

i try to insert value in MySQL database from this code

```
  if(jTextFieldName.getText().isEmpty()
            || jTextFieldLastName.getText().isEmpty()
            || jTextFieldBirthDay.getText().isEmpty()
            || jTextFieldEmail.getText().isEmpty()
            || jTextFieldUserName.getText().isEmpty()
             || jPasswordField1.getPassword().length == 0){ 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"فیلد هارا پر کنید");
             return;    }

//        String name = jTextFieldName.getText();
//        String lastname = jTextFieldLastName.getText();
//        String email = jTextFieldEmail.getText();
//        String username = jTextFieldUserName.getText();
//        char[] password = jPasswordField1.getPassword();


        String sql = String.format(" INSERT INTO register VALUES (\'%S\' , \'%S\',\'%S\', \'%S\' ,\'%S\' ,\'%S\')"
                , jTextFieldName.getText() ,jTextFieldLastName.getText(),jTextFieldBirthDay.getText()
                ,jTextFieldEmail.getText(), jTextFieldUserName.getText(), String.valueOf(jPasswordField1.getPassword()) );

     try {
         java.sql.Statement s = con.createStatement();
         s.executeQuery(sql);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ".: موفق :.");
     } 

      catch (SQLException ex) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"اطلاعات اشتباه وارد شده");
         Logger.getLogger(RegisterForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
```

when run this code i recived this exception :

```
   Feb 01, 2014 4:29:05 PM Qolak.RegisterForm jButtonSubmitActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:929)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkForDml(StatementImpl.java:438)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1379)
    at Qolak.RegisterForm.jButtonSubmitActionPerformed(RegisterForm.java:199)
    at Qolak.RegisterForm.access$100(RegisterForm.java:18)
    at Qolak.RegisterForm$2.actionPerformed(RegisterForm.java:65)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: `INSER INTO`. You forgot a T

Comment: Your sql query is incorrect. Replace **INSER** by **INSERT**

Comment: And you also forgot to learn about prepared statements. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, and will fail as soon as the user enters a single quote in any of the fields. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: @ZouZou , Correct missing "T" in my code but  received new exception .

Comment: SQL injection.  You should learn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the `INSERT` mistake others have mentioned..

Why in the world are you doing *this*?

```
String sql = String.format(" INSER INTO register VALUES (\'%S\' , \'%S\',\'%S\', \'%S\' ,\'%S\' ,\'%S\')"
```

Use a [**`PreparedStatement`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). Besides making your situation alot cleaner, it will help you avoid SQL Injection

Something like this

```
String query = "INSERT INTO register VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, jTextFieldName.getText());
ps.setString(2, jTextFieldLastName.getText());
ps.setString(3, jTextFieldBirthDay.getText());
ps.setString(4, jTextFieldEmail.getText());
ps.setString(5, jTextFieldUserName.getText());
ps.setString(6, String.valueOf(jPasswordField1.getPassword()));

ps.executeUpdate();
```

---

See more on [**How to Use PreparedStatement**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

---

Another error spotted. Look the exception message

> Can not issue data manipulation statements with **`executeQuery()`**.

`executeQuery()` returns a `ResultSet`. It's for when you want to query the database and return data. In your case, you only wanted to update the datebase, so instead you should have used `s.executeUpdate(sql)`

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT statement is missing the "T"...